# How to correctly distribute root-CA's?

Tags: security, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, ca

Lets say I have a signing-CA

I want to distribute the signing-CA PEM to my clients

What is best practice for distributing the PEM?

- Just allow publicly to be downloaded?
- Just for signed in users?
- Any other mechanism?

Seems to be that providing a public or at least restricted download link is totally sufficient. Is that correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no secret to a certificate, they're routinely published to unauthenticated HTTP (not S, though you can do both) as part of Authority Information Access chaining.

If you're a self-signed/root CA there's a trust bootstrapping problem, where your users have to take it on faith that you are you (and that they don't get the wrong cert from the Man in the Middle).  An HTTPS endpoint helps with that; as does embedding the certificate in an Authenticode-or-otherwise-signed client tool.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Exactly what I was thinking - thanks for the confirmation and clarification. I was thinking to provide the download link via HTTPS (not self-signed, but e.g. lets encrypt). Thanks again!